# Exibir quando o usuário está digitando no chat

Tags: jquery

Tenho um chat desenvolvido em PHP e JQuery e quero mostrar quando um usuário está digitando. Alguém sabe como desenvolver?

A idéia é quando um dos usuário esteja digitando, o outro receber uma mensagem parecida com a da imagem abaixo: Fulano está digitando

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o código que já desenvolveu. Mostrar o que?

Comment: Quando tiver dois usuários conversando e um deles digitando, quero que o outro veja alguma mensagem ou imagem que mostre que um deles está digitando. o Chat em si está funcionando, mas quero implementar esta funcionalidade.

Comment: A pergunta é até boa, mas precisa de mais detalhes para que se possa obter uma resposta. Por isso marquei para fechar.